# Поиск в массиве PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Имеется следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE '{Гольф,"американский футбол","русский футбол"}' = ANY (tags)
```

который не работает.

Структура таблицы post

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('post_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    blog_id integer,
    cat_id integer,
    name character varying(500),
    translate character varying(500),
    anons character varying(1000),
    source character varying(1000),
    text text,
    photo character varying(100),
    tags character varying[],
    plus integer default 0,
    minus integer default 0,
    comments integer default 0,
    share integer default 0,
    views integer default 0,
    del integer,
    deltime integer,
    time integer,
    timeedit integer
);
```

Необходимо вывести статьи, у которых имеется минимум один из перечисленных тегов. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как правильный вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE tags && '{Гольф,"американский футбол","русский футбол"}'::character varying[]
```